# Passing data to component created with navigational class

Tags: react-native, navigation, redux

I've been reading this article:
https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-2-implementing-redux-c6acbf66eca1#.agnioxycv

and implemented this navigation solution with redux and NavigationCardStack. What I don't understand is what would be efficient way to pass data to the component created in NavRoot class.
So for instance there is this About component and I need to pass some sort of data to it, could be anything. How should I go about it not increaseing complexity too much?

The only way I see now is by passing data to NavRoot component itself, but that would really escalate complexity and defeat the purpose of navigation class being only about navigation.

Comment: Can you post the minimum amount of code necessary for someone to answer your question?

Comment: this is theoretical question. Code is in the article

Comment: Unless readers need to read the whole article I would recommend extracting the parts that are necessary for understanding your question if you want to mazimise your response rate.